# How can I compare two elements in a same array?

Tags: java, arrays, junit, junit4, dice

I want to write the test case with Junit for my ParOfDice class. But I do not know, how can I compare the elements of the same array. Not two differents array.

```
public class Wuerfelpaar {     // ParOfDice//

    //Erstellungs des Arrays
    private int[] wuerfel = new int[2];

    //Konstruktur des Klasses
    public Wuerfelpaar() {
        this.roll();
        this.pasch();
    }


    public void roll() {

        // Liefert die Länge vor der for-Schleife. Dies wird schneller sein, als wir es nicht sind
        // Immer wieder durch den Bereich navigieren.
        int length = wuerfel.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            wuerfel[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            System.out.println(wuerfel[i]);


        }
    }
    //Falls die Elemente des Arrays (beide Wuerfel) gleich sind
    //Kriegen wir eine Meldung, dass das Pasch ist.
    //Mit diese Struktur, sind die Klassen wiederrufbar.

    public void pasch(){
        if (wuerfel[0] == wuerfel[1]){
            System.out.println("PASCH");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No different than you would compare two different variables. Also, you are comparing those two elements already in your `pasch` method, aren't you?

Comment: yeah i did it.. but how can i write it in test case?
And what else should I test in these class?

Comment: Same as with every other case. `assertEqual(wuerfel[0], wuerfel[1])`. I really don't see the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Testing `pasch()`

I would add a getter method:

```
public int[] getWuerfel() {
   return wuerfel;
}
```

and a boolean verification method:

```
public boolean istPaar() {
   if(wuerfel[0] == wuerfel[1]) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

to `Wuerfelpaar`. Then in your JUnit test you can do something like the following:

```
Wuerfelpaar wp = new Wuerfelpaar();
int[] wuerfel = wp.getWuerfel();
if(wp.istPaar()) {
   assertEqual(wuerfel[0], wuerfel[1]);
}
else {
   assertNotEqual(wuerfel[0], wuerfel[1]);
}
```

---

### Other Tests

As far as other unit tests go, I don't think you really need to test other parts of this class. But if you are determined, I would write a test for `roll()` using the getter method above and then checking that both numbers in the `wuerfel` array are between **1** and **6**.

Comment: can you please tell me, how can write methode for checking both numbers in wuerfel array?

Comment: @SasanNami, To check the numbers you would use something like `assertTrue((wuerfel[0] <= 6) && (wuerfel[0] >= 1))` and the same for `wuerfel[1]`. Again, this level of detail of testing is hardly ever necessary, but if it helps you learn your way around JUnit, it can be helpful in some way.